# Correct way to use Autofac with Factory Pattern?

Tags: c#, winforms, autofac, factory-pattern

IN a Winforms project, I have set up Autofac and Factory Pattern and it looks like it's working as expected. However, I'm still not sure whether the following is best practice.

The factory class is:

```
public static class Client
{
    public static readonly IRequestFactory RequestFactory = new RequestFactory();
}

public class Configuration
{
    public IContainer Container { get; private set; }

    public Configuration()
    {
        var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
        builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies())
            .Where(t => t.Name.EndsWith("Request"))
            .AsImplementedInterfaces()
            .InstancePerLifetimeScope();

        Container = builder.Build();
    }
}

public class RequestFactory : IRequestFactory, IDisposable
{
    private ILifetimeScope scope;

    public RequestFactory()
    {
        scope = Client.Configuration.Container.BeginLifetimeScope();
    }

    public T Get<T>()
    {
        return scope.Resolve<T>();
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        if (scope != null)
        {
            scope.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

Then, classes in separate assemblies have the `IRequestFactory` as a ctor parameter.

Is the above the correct way to implement factor pattern with Autofac or is there a better way?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish?  Why do you want to have a Factory and DI, at least in your example your factory layer is completely redundant, that could easily all be done in DI alone.  Do you maybe want child/nested containers?: https://autofaccn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/lifetime/

Comment: @Thymine What do I pass to the classes in the separate assemblies then? The container itself?

Comment: What type of application is it?

Comment: @thebfactor Winforms.

Comment: Classes usually get passed interfaces with implementations injected by the DI.  When its all working right the DI is almost invisible in the code.There are a wide variety of ways to set DI up, though.  Some of them have registries classes that you use to wire something up in different contexts, but you may not need that.

Comment: If you need the assemblies getting an implementation (which first I'd suggest avoiding, ideally you would have all the dependencies specified in the constructors/methods of the classes in the assembly), you could have them have a dependency on https://github.com/unitycontainer/commonservicelocator, that would allow you to swap out the specific DI library without modifying the Assemblies, and assemblies should not register anything themselves, the application should have the registries (for an internal library your solution is probably fine, but avoid expanding it beyond the CSL's interface)